# Calculate if point is inside polygon defined by matrix

Tags: matrices, geometry

I'm working with SVG file inside C# application and I need to calculate if given point is inside given polygon.

Its all good for me when my polygons come in X-Y coords for points defining that polygon, like:

```
<polygon points="157.812,142.567 156.481,147.782 160.866,148.941 162.206,143.558" />
```

(4 sets of x, y coordinates for each point)

So my problem starts when I get polygon defined with matrix, like:

```
<rect x="166.067" y="153.656" transform="matrix(-0.2387 0.9711 -0.9711 -0.2387 360.4944 28.7338)" width="5.834" height="4.031" />
```

I understand the numbers inside matrix function, matrix(scaleX skewX skewY scaleY translateX translateY).

I am asking for help with either formula that will calculate if XY point is inside that "matrixed" polygon or the calculation that will return XY coordinate of each polygon corner point. I think in 100% cases i have 4 corner polygon.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/) can help you.

Comment: OMG so much text and formulas :) Math and geometry are so annoying. Thank you, I will take a close look at it when I get a chance.